# How to add "System Administrator" back as a member of a community?

Tags: community, profile

In a scratch org, I foolishly removed the "System Administrator" profile from the Members Selected Profiles of a Community and now the "Workspaces" and "Builder" links are no longer available. That means I can't just re-add the "System Administrator" profile. And when I try to push code in (for use by a second Community instance) using SFDX I get this sort of error:

> Error  force-app/main/default/contentassets/logo.asset  We can't
>   install the package because you're not a member of the community
>   Portal. To install it, first add yourself to the community.

Is there any way out of this? I can create a new scratch org, but wonder about this happening in production and so leaving a production Community in a bad state.

Comment: Have you tried pushing in access for the System Admin within the `NetworksMemberGroups` in the [networks](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_network.htm) metadata type? Or do you get the same error message?

Comment: My approach: create a new scratch org :)

Comment: I've kicked off another scratch org setup...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty way to do it:

You can use the Developer Console's Query Editor tab (at the bottom of the window) to run a query on the Network Metadata object to get the Id of the Community/Digital Experience Site you want to add the profile back to:

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Network = '<Community Site Name>'

ex: SELECT Id, Name FROM Network = 'Partner Portal'
result ex: 0DB6a0000001234abc, 'Partner Portal'
```

and then run another query to get the Profile Id of the profile you want:

```
SELECT id, Name FROM Profile WHERE Name = '<Profile Name>'
 
ex: SELECT id, Name FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator' OR Name = 'Partner Portal User'
result ex: 00e6a0000001234abc, 'System Administrator'
           00e6a0000001765AAC, 'Partner Portal User'
```

With those two IDs (NetworkID and ProfileID) you will be able to prepare a csv file that will look like this, to add the System Admin profile back as a member of the community **(Note that the profile ID is stored in the ParentId field)**:

```
NetworkId,ParentId
0DB6a0000001234abc,00e6a0000001234abc
```

Save it as a CSV and insert it with Dataloader into the NetworkMemberGroup metadata table, making sure to map those columns properly.

And flippity jippity, voilà, it's done!

Comment: Hi Joseph, Makes sense. Presumably you could also insert the `NetworkMemberGroup` via some execute anonymous Apex too.